# How to remap “ctrl+w+shift+f” to “gf” in vim to go to line of file under cursor in split window?

Tags: vim

<kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>+<kbd>Shift+f</kbd> will go to line of file under cursor in split window. I want to set a small shortcut say `gf` which should be mapped to <kbd>Ctrl+w</kbd>+<kbd>Shift+f</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [normal mode `map`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapmode-nvo):

```
nnoremap <leader>f <c-w>F
```

I have used [`Leader`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#mapleader) instead of `g`, since `Leader` is typically used for defining such custom shortcuts. It has the default value of `\`, so you would type `\f` in normal mode. `<c-w>` is Vim's notation for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> is, well, `F`.